# Msbuild gives error while invoking custom task

Tags: c#

I have created custom task in C# library project. Within this project I have added service reference. Using this service reference object i have written code in `excute` method, to invoke service function.

After building this library project, dll and dll.config files are generated.

dll.config has service endpoint descriptions which is same as app.config.

Now i am trying to invoke this task(which internally calling service function) through msbuild. But it giving error - " Service end points could not located......"

Can someone help to provide correct approach to solve above problem?

Comment: What task are you referring to?

Comment: From msbuild proj file, i am referring to custom task (Class Name) ..

Comment: I would say you need to add endpoints configuration to your msbuild proj file config.

Comment: Do you mean to say msbuild.exe has config file. And I need to modify it, to include service reference ?

Comment: No. What do you mean by "msbuild proj file"? Can you add you solution structure and more detailed steps description in terms of "executing task".

Comment: In this scenario, I have written custom task in C# which outputs DLL.

Comment: And I am referring this DLL from proj file to invoke task. And I am giving this proj file as input to msbuild to call required task

Comment: Hi @ Guru Stron I have open another thread on which I have posted Details. Can you please go through it - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52355977/unable-to-invoke-custom-task-referring-wcf-service-function-through-msbuild